# Change `base_compiledir` to save compiled files in another directory

Tags: python, theano

`theano.base_compiledir` refers to the directory where the compiled files are stored.

Is there a way where I could permanently set `theano.base_compiledir` to a different location, perhaps by modifying the content of some internal Theano files ?

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html does explain ways for configuring `theano` in some aspect but I still couldn't address my question.

I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html) explains, you can set this, or any other Theano config flag, permanently by altering either the `THEANO_FLAGS` environment variable (e.g. in your `~/.bashrc` file) or using a `~/.theanorc` file.

For the former, add a line like this to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export THEANO_FLAGS="base_compiledir=/some/path"
```

For the latter, create a `~/.theanorc` file with contents that look like this:

```
[global]
base_compiledir=/some/path
```

In either case, you'll probably want to add a bunch of other flags such as `device=`, `floatX=`, etc.

If you alter your `~/.bashrc` file the changes won't take effect in any active terminals unless you run `source ~/.bashrc` in each one or simply close the terminals and start new ones.